# What does "Was hat Kim Jong Un mit Texas vor?" mean?

Tags: grammar, verb

> **hat... mit... vor**

According to my dictionary, this is *etw mit jdm/etw vorhaben* = to intend doing sth with sb/sth.
So, the question about Kim should be rendered in English as "What does Kim intend doing with Texas?" Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use:

> What does Kim intend to do with Texas?

Here are some references that suggest `intend to do` as well as `intend doing` can be used, while the former seems to be more common:

- [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=beabsichtigen%2C+etw.+zu+tun)
- [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/intend?q=intend)
- [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/intend)

Comment: Yes, according to [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) it's far far more common to say "intend to do".

Comment: Many thanks indeed. (How would that be translated into German?)

Comment: @indoxica The German translation is `Was hat Kim mit Texas vor?` or `Was beabsichtigt Kim mit Texas zu tun?`.

Comment: @indoxica I would go with "danke schön".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right and your translation is correct, as far as I my English competence reaches.